# Using MVCGrid.net, how can I change sort/filter still have browser back button function

Tags: mvcgrid.net

I'm using MVCGrid.net (http://mvcgrid.net).  I want to change sort/filter options and still click back in my browser to return to the previous page.  because this control leverages browser history, when i click back i return to the previous sort direction instead of the previous page.  That's really great if I want that functionality -- don't get me wrong. but i don't always want that.  it would be nice if there's a way to disable it (or circumvent it).  is there?

Edit:
Perhaps instead of using history.pushState() the axd, maybe using history.replaceState() would be a better experience?

Answer (score 1):

I forked this project on GitHub and added a .WithBrowserNavigationMode to the grid builder.  I LOVE the feature of this control that I can come back from another page and still have my latest page/sort/filter preserved by leveraging browser history.  But MOST of the time i only care about my last view.  I don't want to click the back button to go to previous pages/sorts/filters.

Now if you only want to preserve the latest action that you did on a grid in your browser history, just do this:

```
MVCGridDefinitionTable.Add("YourGrid", new MVCGridBuilder<YourViewModel>()
    .WithBrowserNavigationMode(BrowserNavigationMode.PreserveLatestGridAction)
```

Currently only works with my fork of the code base unless/until my pull request is merged to master.  Here's where to get it:  https://github.com/johnpreed/MVCGrid.Net